# How would I parse this txt file into csv?

Tags: python, parsing

How would I parse this into a csv file?

[{"new_match":0,"original_sid":146,"recommended_sid":342,"score":10.442},{"new_match":0,"original_sid":146,"recommended_sid":11,"score":12.4652521},{"new_match":0,"original_sid":238,"recommended_sid":55,"score":11.459223},{"new_match":0,"original_sid":238,"recommended_sid":654,"score":12.33},{"new_match":0,"original_sid":203,"recommended_sid":119,"score":2.384},{"new_match":0,"original_sid":203,"recommended_sid":274274,"score":18.36}]

is my ad.txt file.

I want to make a data frame with columns 'new_match', 'original_sid', 'recommended_sid', and 'score'. Is there any way of doing this quickly?

Comment: Hi there, perhaps use `csv.reader`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a json list of dictionaries to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340568/how-to-parse-a-json-list-of-dictionaries-to-csv)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like json, so you should be able to like this. This will print your CSV to output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import csv
import sys

# pass in your ad.txt
d = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))
csvw = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=['new_match', 'original_sid', 'recommended_sid', 'score'])
csvw.writeheader()
for i in d:
    csvw.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [
    {"new_match":0,"original_sid":146,"recommended_sid":342,"score":10.442
    {"new_match":0,"original_sid":146,"recommended_sid":11,"score":12.4652521},
    {"new_match":0,"original_sid":238,"recommended_sid":55,"score":11.459223},
    {"new_match":0,"original_sid":238,"recommended_sid":654,"score":12.33},
    {"new_match":0,"original_sid":203,"recommended_sid":119,"score":2.384},
    {"new_match":0,"original_sid":203,"recommended_sid":274274,"score":18.36}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
```